# $\theta_0=1$ in MA process

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, moving-average

Let $X_t$ be an MA$(q)$ process defined as
\begin{equation}
X_{t}=\mu +\overset{q}{\underset{j=0}{\sum }}\theta_{j}\varepsilon_{t-j}=\mu +\theta_{0}\varepsilon_{t}+\theta_{1}\varepsilon_{t-1}+\theta_{2}\varepsilon_{t-2} + \ldots
\end{equation}
where we ask that $\theta_0=1$. This requirement is for "identifiability purpose". What does the latter mean mathematically I cannot find any explicit and rigorous explanation of why we ask that $\theta_0=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the sole purpose of requiring $\theta_0 = 1$ is for "identifiability purpose". To see why it is so, first you should understand that a complete specification of an $MA(q)$ model (or more generally, an $ARMA(p, q)$ model) includes not only the equation
\begin{align}
X_t = \mu + \theta_0\varepsilon_{t} + \theta_1\varepsilon_{t - 1} + \cdots + \theta_q\varepsilon_{t - q}, 
\end{align}
but also the distributional form of the process $\{\varepsilon_t\}$, which is typically written as $\{\varepsilon_t\} \sim \text{WN}(0, \sigma^2)$. The parameter space of the $MA(q)$ model is thus $\Theta = \{(\mu, \theta_0, \ldots, \theta_q, \sigma): \sigma > 0, \mu, \theta_0, \ldots, \theta_q \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

If we do not impose any constraint on $\theta_0$, then the model is non-identifiable, meaning that different vectors of $(\mu, \theta_0, \ldots, \theta_q, \sigma)$ would give the same distribution of $\{X_t\}$.  For simplicity, assuming $q = 1$. It is easy to see that $(0, 4, 4, 1)$ and $(0, 2, 2, 2)$ give the same distribution of $\{X_t\}$.  In particular,
\begin{align}
& X_t = 4\varepsilon_t + 4\varepsilon_{t - 1}, \; \{\varepsilon_t\} \sim \text{WN}(0, 1), \\
& X_t' = 2\varepsilon_t + 2\varepsilon_{t - 1}, \; \{\varepsilon_t\} \sim \text{WN}(0, 4)
\end{align}
would have exactly the same autocovariance function.

This non-identifiability can be eliminated by requiring $\theta_0 = 1$.  Continuing the above example, if $X_t = \mu + \varepsilon_t + \theta_1\varepsilon_{t - 1}, \{\varepsilon_t\} \sim \text{WN}(0, \sigma^2)$ and $X_t' = \eta + \varepsilon_t + \phi_1\varepsilon_{t - 1}, \{\varepsilon_t\} \sim \text{WN}(0, \tau^2)$ have the same distribution, then it must hold $\mu = \eta, \theta_1 = \phi_1$ and $\sigma = \tau$.  I will leave that as an exercise to you.

The same idea is frequently used in statistics to maintain model identifiability. Perhaps the most well-known example in this regard is the one-way ANOVA model $y_{ij} = \mu + \alpha_j + \epsilon_{ij}$. Without imposing any constraint on $\{\alpha_j\}$, the model is non-identifiable.  To ensure the identifiability, people usually use the constraint $\alpha_1 = 0$ (just like in the $MA(q)$ model case) or the constraint $\alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_K = 0$.  For more details, I refer you to  read Section 6.2 of *Modern Applied Statistics with S* by W. Venables, and B. Ripley. There are more similar notable examples in time series as well, for example, the first component of a cointegration vector is usually set as $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hi: you need the $\hat{\epsilon}_{t}$, namely the estimates of the error terms, in order to estimate the model.

Specifically, the numerical way to obtain the parameter estimates of an MA(q) is to calculate the $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \hat{\epsilon_i}^2$ for the sample and then minimize that term numerically. ( well, that's not exactly how it's done but, for purposes of this question, it's fine ).

Note that the estimate of $\epsilon_t$ at time $t$ ( during the $t$th loop of the optimization routine ), namely $\hat{\epsilon}_t = y_t - \hat{\mu}  - \hat{\theta}_{1}\epsilon_{t-1} - \hat{\theta}_{2}\epsilon_{t-2} - \ldots \hat{\theta}_{q}\epsilon_{t-q}$.

So, if you did have an unknown  coefficient on $\epsilon_{t}$, there would be no way to calculate the estimate, $\hat{\epsilon_t}$ and therefore, no objective function to minimize.

There are particular difficulties that come up with the MA(q) that make the optimization task even more difficult than what I described above. But the reason for needing $\theta_{0}$ does not change and is hopefully clearer now. Note that, technically, $\theta_0$ doesn't have to be 1.0 but it has to be a known constant rather than an unknown parameter.

P.S. : If you want a much better and thorough explanation of numerical techniques for estimating time series models ( not necessarily ARMA but some of it is devoted to that ), I highly recommend Andrew Harvey's " The Econometric Analysis of Time Series". He tends to be quite terse so there's an ton of info-details compacted into each page ( and once in a while, skipped steps ) but definitely worth the effort. I know of no other texts that cover the material he covers, atleast from a numerical-estimation framework.

Another P.S. : Note that I really should be starting the sum of the $\hat{\epsilon_i}^2$ at $i = q+1$ ( because $q$ observations are lost because we need the first $q$ observations in order to obtain the first $\hat{\epsilon}$ at $t = q+1$ but these are details that I'd prefer to not deal with because they don't effect the reasoning.